# C++ template recursion stop condition

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

Suppose I have the code:

```
template<size_t num> void actLoop(float* result, const float* rvector,
                                          size_t* xs, size_t indexIn=0)
{
    for(xs[num]=0; xs[num]<N; ++xs[num])
    {
        size_t index = indexIn+xs[num]*strides[num];
        if(num>0)
            actLoop<num-1>(result,rvector,xs,index);
        else
            result[index] = work(rvector,index,xs);
    }
}
```

It should create nested loop with nest level of `num`. When I try to compile it, I get compiler error about too deep recursion, i.e. seems compiler doesn't eliminate if(0>0) statement.

Is there a good way to make this happen, not having to create separate specialization for `num=0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a way, Andrei Alexandrescu has presented it in one of his talks at [Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013):

```
template<size_t num> void actLoop(float* result, const float* rvector,
                                          size_t* xs, size_t indexIn=0)
{
    for(xs[num]=0; xs[num]<N; ++xs[num])
    {
        size_t index = indexIn+xs[num]*strides[num];
        if(num>0)
            actLoop<(num > 0 ? num-1 : num)>(result,rvector,xs,index);
        else
            result[index] = work(rvector,index,xs);
    }
}
```

This refers to the same instantiation of `actLoop` if `num` is `0`, therefore breaking the infinite instantiation.

Answer (score 5):

The `if( num > 0 )` is a runtime condition. The recursion is happening at compile time. So no, there is no way to avoid the specialization for `num = 0`.

Why is it a problem though, to create the specialization for `num = 0` ?

Comment: The problem is one of compactness of source and avoiding duplication of code.

Answer (score 3):

The clearest indication that something's wrong here is `num`.  There's a difference between nonce names you don't need to describe and confused names you can't.  You're trying to make `num` mean two different things, the number of loop layers remaining and the array index you're using for bookkeeping.

```
template<size_t nloops>
void actLoop(float* result, const float* rvector, size_t* xs, size_t index=0)
{       // loop layers (nloops>=1): loop
        auto xs_index=nloops-1;
        for ( int i=0 ; i < N ; ++i ) {
                xs[xs_index] = i;
                actLoop<nloops-1>(result, rvector, xs, index + i*strides[xs_index]);
        }
}

template<>
void actLoop<0>(float* result, const float* rvector, size_t* xs, size_t index)
{       // no loops left: work
                result[index] = work(rvector,index,xs);
}
```

Comment: Although your example shows good separation of loops-generating magic from the code, my question was about avoiding explicit specialization. Still I have to admit that your code is more readable than mine would finally be, so +1.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it was far enough from what you asked for I wouldn't have posted it except I think most places that seem to need `if (n) func<n-(n>0)>()`-style trickery would be better off with something like this.

Answer (score 1):

A way that doesn't block full inlining with a final recursive call is:

```
template<size_t num> void actLoop(float* result, const float* rvector,
                                      size_t* xs, size_t indexIn=0, std::false_type )
{
  result[index] = work(rvector,index,xs);
}

template<size_t num> void actLoop(
    float* result,
    const float* rvector,
    size_t* xs,
    size_t indexIn=0,
    std::true_type unused=std::true_type()
  )
{
  for(xs[num]=0; xs[num]<N; ++xs[num])
  {
    size_t index = indexIn+xs[num]*strides[num];
    actLoop<num-1>(result, rvector, xs, index, typename std::conditional<(num>0), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type());
   }
}
```

where we call a different overload on the -1 case than on the other cases.

Another approach would be to bounce the function call to a `template class`, where you specialize around the `num = -1` case.

Comment: `typename std::conditional<(num>0), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type()` or `std::integral_constant<bool, (num>0)>{}` which is slightly shorter ;)

Comment: "A way that doesn't block full inlining with a final recursive call is:" There's no final recursive call, though it's up to the optimizer to throw out that branch `if(0>0)`. Did you compile it and saw whether it is inlined or not?

Answer (score 0):

With modern C++ (since C++17) this problem can be solved much more straightforwardly: by using [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) statement. Here's the modified version of the code in the OP (with some dummy wrapper to make it compilable):

```
#include <stddef.h>

float work(const float*,size_t,const size_t*) { return 0; }
const unsigned N=5;
size_t strides[10];

template<size_t num> void actLoop(float* result, const float* rvector,
                                          size_t* xs, size_t indexIn=0)
{
    for(xs[num]=0; xs[num]<N; ++xs[num])
    {
        size_t index = indexIn+xs[num]*strides[num];
        if constexpr(num>0)
            actLoop<num-1>(result,rvector,xs,index);
        else
            result[index] = work(rvector,index,xs);
    }
}

int main()
{
    float res[10], rvec[10]={};
    size_t xs[10], str[10]={};
    actLoop<5>(res,rvec,xs);
}
```